# Python Google API Campaign Manager inserting creative asset is showing success, but isn't appearing in advertiser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm using the campaign manager API to upload a local file into an advertiser; the script works all the way through without any errors. However, when checking the advertiser directly, there isn't a new creative asset. The changelogs also don't show any new changes. The script run (without the google authentication - OAuth 2.0, which is working to expectation on other calls):

```
 def upload_creative_asset(
    service, profile_id, advertiser_id, asset_name,path_to_asset_file,
    asset_type):
  """Uploads a creative asset and returns an assetIdentifier."""
  # Construct the creative asset metadata
  creative_asset = {
      'assetIdentifier': {
          'name': asset_name,
          'type': asset_type
      }
  }

  media = MediaFileUpload(path_to_asset_file, mimetype='image/gif')
  if not media.mimetype():
    media = MediaFileUpload(path_to_asset_file, 'application/octet-stream')

  response = service.creativeAssets().insert(
      advertiserId=advertiser_id,
      profileId=profile_id,
      media_body=media,
      body=creative_asset)

  return response

path_to_creative = "automated_dcm_loading/test.gif"

upload_creative_request = upload_creative_asset(service,advertiser_id='10229XXX',profile_id='6414XXX',asset_name='test.gif',path_to_asset_file=path_to_creative,asset_type='image')

upload_creative_request.execute()
```

The response is:

```
{'kind': 'dfareporting#creativeAssetMetadata',
 'assetIdentifier': {'type': 'IMAGE', 'name': 'test.gif'},
 'id': '475828XXX',
 'richMedia': False}
```

This tells me it's worked but doesn't appear in campaign manager anywhere.

UPDATE: This is only half the process to get an asset to appear in campaign manager. The next step for those who need this is to use this *exact* output in a creatives().insert() function to wrap the *asset* with a *creative*. Without this creative step your asset/image/video will sit on a server somewhere with nowhere for it be shown.

Comment: What authorization method are you using?

Comment: Hi, using OAuth 2.0

Comment: Who are you logging in as? are you sure your checking the right user, your getting an Id back which means it has been inserted.

Comment: It's a user role set up through cloud console, and yes I agree - unfortunately, it isn't appearing anywhere, I can see all the profile's activity (creating placements, campaigns) but no creatives. Do you know if I can add extra logs?